# How to assign Id and field value to Hidden field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I have a `gridview` with few `rows` and `columns`, with `ListBox` Controls in columns.

**Markup**:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvDataEntry" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    <Columns>
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ListBox ID="lstBox1" ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick()" runat="server" CssClass="listBox"></asp:ListBox>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ListBox ID="lstBox2" ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick()" runat="server" CssClass="listBox"></asp:ListBox>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ListBox ID="lstBox3" ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick()" runat="server" CssClass="listBox"></asp:ListBox>
</ItemTemplate>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Displayed as

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Name         |  Column1  |  Column2   | Column3
-----------------------------------------------------
FieldName    |  LB1      |   LB2      |   LB3      
----------------------------------------------------
FieldName 1  |  LB1      |   LB2      |   LB3
-----------------------------------------------------
```

When I double click the `Listbox` I want to do some functionalities, so I have added the hidden field outside the gridview as

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="ListBox1Hidden"
            runat="server" />
```

**Javascript**

```
<script lang="javascript">
        function ListBox1_DoubleClick() {
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    </script>
```

On **Page Load**

```
       if (Request.Params["ListBox1Hidden"] != null)
        {          
            //This means It was double click            
        }
```

Now when I double click the `ListBox` this event fires. Now I want o get the `Name` , `RowIndex` and `Id` of the ListBox Clicked

For Ex:

If I double clicked the `LB1` of firs row I want to get Name : `FieldName`, Id: `lstBox1`  and RowIndex.

My doubt is, Can it can be achieved by the only one hidden field as I did. If so how to do it?

Else, should I have to include every `HiddenField` in the `ItemTemplate` to achieve this.

Which one helps me to achieve this, and provide me code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the columns value in your javascript function. Like this:

```
'<%# Eval("ColumnName") %>'
```

For exmaple we have this double click event:

```
ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick()"
```

Try to change this to:

```
ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick('<%# Eval(\"ColumnName\") %>')"
```

So in this way you can pass any column's value as a parameter to javascript function.

Note: Within the double quotes "ColumnName" we have to use the proper escape character.

Comment: how about to find the Id and rowIndex @Muhammad Idrees

Comment: For 'Id' field you must know what field name in the binding source represents the Id field and just place that field name in place of 'ColumnName'. And for RowIndex try this '<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>'

Comment: If you don't mind can you place the code, I'm really confused

Comment: In your code segment, just replace: 
ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick()"
with:
ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick('<%# Eval(\"Id\") %>', '<%# Eval(\"Name\") %>', '<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>')"
Where Id and Name are your datasource columns, you can change according to your column names.

Comment: What about my javascript function, how to retrieve and add those to my hidden field

Comment: Javascript function will become:
 function ListBox1_DoubleClick(id, name, rowIndex) {
  //here you can use these parameters
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }

Comment: I'm asking to which properties to the hidden field I have to set, because I don't find many. And I have to retrieve in the page load

Comment: Can I set these properties in the page load,I mean code behind

Comment: Put three hidden fields. In javascript function set parameter values in corresponding hidden fields.  To set value in hidden field, you can use this code $('MyHiddenFieldClientID').val('MyValue'); . And then in page_load you can access hidden field's value as: MyHiddenValueServerID.Value